Can a RabbitMQ exchange route messages with dynamic bindings?
Just checking to be sure: in RabbitMQ, can I have an exchange whose bindings are dynamic? By that I mean that I don't have to hardcode bindings like:

header/routing key action.x routed to queue actionrequests.x
header/routing key action.y routed to queue actionrequests.y
header/routing key action.z routed to queue actionrequests.z
...many more of these

Ideally this would be managed by a single dynamic binding like (pseudosyntax):

header/routing key action.{actionName} routed to queue actionrequests.$actionName

After researching for a while, I couldn't find how to do this (apart of course from the default binding, but then again it's said to be "bound to every queue based on the routing key").
